# input type="image" vs request headers

Tags: html, jsp

I want to display the image ,my input type is image,i want to get it as a parameter and show in a jsp page.and after i hope to send to the database.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="002"> 
**`<input type="file"  name="pc" src="images/(10).jpg">`**
 <input type="hidden" name="dsc"  value="watch2">
 <input type="hidden" name="price" value="3000">  
 <input class="button item_add cbp-vm-icon cbp-vm-add" id="add"    type="submit" value="Add to cart" name=""/></div> </form>
```

---

next jsp page

```
 <input type="image" name="pc" src="<%=request.getParameter("pc")%>"/>
```

Comment: What, exactly is your question?

Comment: 1st page i have hidden image,i want show it in my next page,but value was null

Comment: The `input type=image` is meant for when you want your form's submit button to be an image. It's not for transferring an image to another page. Instead you should use an `input type=file` and then the value can be transferred.

Comment: i didn't know,tnx,but,i want to put default image,when i used input type=file it asked to choose a file

Comment: Then just use a hidden input field `input type=hidden` and set its value to the image you want to store. Then that data will be transferred with the rest of the form data.

Comment: ok,when i show the image,what should be the input type

Comment: You don't use inputs to show images you use the IMG tag